# window.open losing control in click event handler in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, popup, dom-events

I'm trying to open a new window using `window.open`, in an event handler for a click event:

```
var onButtonClick = function() {
    alert('start');
    window.open('http://www.google.com', 'goog', 'width=800,height=400');
    alert('done');
};
var element = document.getElementById("button");
element.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eGNpe/

I expect an alert saying "start", an alert saying "end", and a window to open.
This works in Chrome on linux but in Firefox 20.0 on Ubunutu, I only get the first alert, suggesting that somewhere in the window.open method, control is lost.

If this was a popup blocker issue, I'd expect some notification that a popup was blocked, and the `window.open` should just return null and continue to throw the second alert.

Any ideas? Am I misusing event handlers or the `window.open` method?

Comment: On Firefox, on Ubuntu, I get both popups.  Try moving the Google window out of the way.

Comment: Yeah I don't see why this wouldn't work. Obviously event handlers are ok (else you won't get the first alert) , and the window.open could hardly be broken... strange ! Are you receiving any error message in the console ?

Comment: On my machine I get nothing on the console, and only the first alert, with no popup opening. I've just tried running this in a fresh Firefox profile and it worked, so it seems likely that this is due to some extension I have installed, or weird configuration.

Comment: I experienced a similar problem on Mac FF20, where anything after the window.open is not executed

Answer (score 0):

After disabling all Firefox extensions, the code above works as expected. This issue may be specific to my own machine and configuration.